# PHP - Plugin de Jquery para filtro de fechas tipo Excel

Tags: php, html, jquery

Hola buen dia tengo un problema al intentar crear un filtro de fechas he probado varios datepicker pero ninguno se parece a excel.

Me refiero a dividirlos en años, dentro de ellos una lista de los meses y finalmente una lista de los dias del mes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si pudieran sugerirme un plugin de JQuery que lo pueda hacer se los agradecería bastante.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar :

https://momentjs.com/

Creando un filtro en javascript que te muestre exactamente de la misma manera, ya que con momentJS controlas todo tipo de datos, (AÑ0, mes, dia, momento del dia, etc) ..

Saludos

Comment: Es decir, no va a hacer todo el trabajo por ti. Solo te da una muuuy buena base para trabajar con tiempos.. Luego hacer el pllugin para mostrar eso, te lo dejo a ti.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo voy a probar